# Remapping Wacom Tablet input on Android 11 using .idc files

Tags: root-access, android-11, stylus, wacom

- OS: Android 11 with root access
- Tablet: One by Wacom Small CTL-471

### The Issue

I'd like to use my Wacom tablet on my Android device. Connected tablet using OTG cable is detected, but it suffers from invalid mapping resulting in heavily squished elipses when circle is drawn on the tablet.

[image]

In landscape mode, the tablet input does not cover the full screen area, resulting only in half of the screen being able to be controlled

[image]

### What I would like to achieve

- remap the tablet input so it is rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees when the device is in portrait mode

and optionally

- rotate in other directions in landscape mode aka. 90°/180°
- define tablet min/max X and Y to limit the useable tablet area and match the proportions of the display - circle on the tablet = true circle on the device

### What I tried

I created `Wacom_Bamboo_One_S_Pen.idc` file in `/system/usr/idc/` with following configuration

```
touch.deviceType = pointer
touch.orientationAware = 1​
```

The configuration file is detected when using `dumpsys input | grep -i wacom​`

```
13: Wacom Bamboo One S Pen
  ConfigurationFile: /system/usr/idc/Wacom_Bamboo_One_S_Pen.idc
Device 13: Wacom Bamboo One S Pen
```

and it does work, as the result when using `dumpsys input`, the `OrientationAware` is now `true`

```
Parameters:
  ...
  OrientationAware: true
```

Now the mapping in landscape mode is better, but still invalid

[image]

Now I tried to modify `xScale` `yScale` and `output.x` `output.y` with samples found online to check if anything changes, like this

```
touch.deviceType = pointer
touch.orientationAware = 1​
output.x = (raw.x - raw.x.min) * (output.width / raw.width)
```

or even using a simple float

```
output.x = 1.0
```

Even though the config file is detected in `dumpsys input | grep -i wacom​` it seems to now be ignored as the values are back to default when checking `dumpsys input` so, `OrientationAware: false` even though the config file says it to be `true`.

What am I doing wrong - is it wrong syntax? My knowledge on this topic is very limited, and I've tried to check [official documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/touch-devices), but still without result, so I'm asking for help.

### Update

Examining other files found on the web resulted in confirmation that it is the wrong syntax. I tried this instead:

```
touch.touchPosition.xymix = 1.0
touch.touchPosition.yxmix = 1.0
```

It seems like `xymix` and `yxmix` would allow to flip the input, but `dumpsys input` reports that these values are still `0.0`. `OrientationAware` stays `true` with these values, indicating acceptable syntax.

Comment: Can this also be used to remap the hardware buttons on a Wacom tablet?